# Internal Server Study Error > pivothigh / pivotlow

Tags: pine-script

I'm having a strange error with my script. I want to convert the ATR into a stochastic for the purposes of determining an appropriate lookback length for my indicators. You can ignore `timeframe_factor`; it's a function that returns an integer based on a fractal period and I've verified it's working properly.

```
atr_timeframe = timeframe_factor(2)
atr_stoch_timeframe = timeframe_factor(3)
atr = atr(atr_timeframe)
atr_stoch = stoch(atr, highest(atr, atr_timeframe), lowest(atr, atr_timeframe), atr_stoch_timeframe) / 100
atr_stoch_period = round(atr_stoch * atr_stoch_timeframe)
pivot_period = atr_stoch_period[2] > atr_stoch_period[1] and atr_stoch_period > atr_stoch_period[1] ? atr_stoch_period[1] : atr_stoch_period
pivot_period := pivot_period < 1 ? 1 : pivot_period
plot(pivothigh(high, pivot_period, 0))
```

The 1st assignment to `pivot_period` is for the sake of using the prior `pivot_period`'s value if a sharp uptick has occurred (beginning of day for example). I've visually verified by plotting `pivot_period` that it shows integers >= 1 on the chart - it's only when using it in `pivothigh` that the error occurs. I've also verified that there are no `na`'s on the chart by using `barssince`. The error doesn't happen if I use a static integer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `max_bars_back` in `study` statement:

```
study("My Study", max_bars_back=5000)
```